# cPanel auto-deploy repository and run npm script

Tags: apache, github, cpanel

I've locally written code for a website that has since been pushed to a private github repository owned by my organization. I would like to set up my Apache web server's subdomain to automatically pull that code every time a push is made to a certain branch of the Github repo.

I've read many documentations and tried many things, nothing seems to be working for me.

Could someone please provide detailed steps or a method that has worked for them in this situation?

**EDIT**

With cPanel's Git Version Control Tool and SSH keys, I've been able to get my repository cloned properly. Now, I still need a way to make cPanel run "npm run start" every time the repository is deployed. Any thoughts?

Comment: did you find a way ?

Comment: @pouyada I've decided to set up my repo in the cPanel Version Control instead, to which I push my code changes. I have a PM2 daemon that keeps the whole thing running constantly, rebuilds and re-runs every time